# Petit FAT file system with a MSP430

Tags: msp430

Is there a way of clearing a file in the petitFAT format?  What I came up with is this:

```
void SDerase(void)
{
    for(;;){
        res = pf_write("\0", 1, &bw);
        if(res || !bw) break;
    }
}
```

So this basically writes NULL characters to the files until it reaches the end.  It works fine, but it's a bit slow.  Erasing a 100 kb file takes roughly 1.5 seconds.  I will be using bigger files later, possibly a few megabytes, so this method would take ages.  Is there another method of erasing a file (.csv or .txt) with the petitFAT file system?

Comment: Why do you need to NULL the contents of your file (your code does *not* delete the file, it just overwrites it!)? Can't you just do a circular log where you reset your file pointer to the beginning when the file gets 'too large'?

Comment: I'm trying to log some data, so if I don't clear it, it is sometimes hard to tell where the new data ends.  

I have another question for you since you seem to be familiar with petitFAT.  If I call the pf_write function by timer interrupt, how do I actually write it to MMC?  From what I've read, it seems like I have to terminate write and reinitiate it again? e.g., this line
    pf_write(0, 0, &bw);

Comment: @us2012
Just to add a bit more to my comment above, I did something like this: `for(;;){ strcat(value,",\n"); res = pf_write(value, strlen(value), &bw);` I didn't call `res = pf_write(0, 0, &bw);` and it seems to work, though I think this might be a bad way to do it.  Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to log some data, so if I don't clear it, it is sometimes
>   hard to tell where the new data ends.

If you are logging ASCII data, this is not a problem. Simply reserve special characters for 'data begins here' and 'data ends here'. Even if you are logging binary data, it may be worth changing the encoding to something like base64 ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 ) to net you special characters for controlling your data sequence (GB memory cards are cheap, and base64 only introduces 33% data overhead).

Alternatively, you could have an extra file that contains the data boundaries for your log files as a number of bytes. This is going to be a hassle with an interface as limited as petitFAT though, as you can only open a single file at a time. Depending on how much RAM and program memory you can spare on your MSP430, you may consider moving to a more feature-rich FAT implementation.

> If I call the pf_write function by timer interrupt, how do I actually
>   write it to MMC? From what I've read, it seems like I have to
>   terminate write and reinitiate it again? e.g., this line pf_write(0,
>   0, &bw);

In a simple logger that does nothing but write sequentially to a single file you shouldn't need to call `pf_write(0,0,&bw)` until you shut down your device entirely. (It may or may not be necessary to do so before seeking to another position.)

If you absolutely want to stick with your 'overwrite entire file' idea, you could try whether first getting the file size and then writing larger blocks of `\0`s instead of single bytes gives you a significant speedup.

Comment: It seems like the start/end character method might not work for me, since I don't know when the file ends.  The SD card may be pulled out any time, so there won't be time for the program to insert an 'end' character quick enough.  But thanks for clarifying about the terminate write function, and writing larger blocks of \0 might be worth a try.

Comment: Can you not add a small physical button that will trigger an "end of data" write followed by a file finalize and a "it's now safe to remove the card"-LED?

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea.  I will probably need to add a few safeguards since I'm letting other people use it as well.  Thanks